# Replace dashes with whitespaces for all elements across a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm building off of these two questions because they don't quite answer my question:
[How to change values in a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458239/how-to-change-values-in-a-tuple)
[Python: Replace "-" with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075572/python-replace-with-whitespace)

If I have a tuple like this:

```
worldstuff = [('Hi', 'Hello-World', 'Earth'), ('Hello-World', 'Hi'), ...]
```

How do I replace dashes with whitespaces for all of the elements across all lists in a tuple? The previous Stack Overflow question covers changing the specific index of one list in a tuple, but not if there are multiple occurances of an element needing to be replaced.

I've tried doing the following, which doesn't quite work:

```
worldstuff_new = [x.replace('-', ' ') for x in worldstuff]
```

But if I do it for a specific list in the tuple, it works for that tuple list. I'm trying to avoid having to do separate lists and instead trying to do it all at once.

```
worldstuff_new = [x.replace('-', ' ') for x in worldstuff[0]]
```

I understand that tuples are immutable, which is why I am having trouble figuring this out. Is this possible? Would appreciate any help - thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Correct expression:

```py
a = [('Hi', 'Hello-World', 'Earth'), ('Hello-World', 'Hi')]
b = [tuple([x.replace('-', ' ') for x in tup]) for tup in a]

>>> b
[('Hi', 'Hello World', 'Earth'), ('Hello World', 'Hi')]
```

A few notes:

1. Please don't clobber builtins (`tuple`).
2. What you have is actually not a tuple, but a list of tuples.
3. As you note, `tuple`s are immutable; but you can always build new tuples from the original ones.
4. (Speed) Why `tuple([x.replace ...])` (tuple of a list comprehension) instead of `tuple(x.replace ...)` (tuple of the output of a generator)? Because the former is slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

first of everything, don't name any variable `tuple` it's a builtin function and when you name a variable `tuple` you miss that `method`

```
def changer(data):
    if type(data) == str:
        return data.replace("-", " ")
    elif type(data) == list:
        return [changer(x) for x in data]
    elif type(data) == tuple:
        return tuple(changer(x) for x in data)
tpl = [('Hi', 'Hello-World', 'Earth'), ('Hello-World', 'Hi')]

changer(tpl)
```

output:

```
[('Hi', 'Hello World', 'Earth'), ('Hello World', 'Hi')]
```

Comment: sorry! thank you for the feedback on variable name, as well as your help with my question

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple_old = [('Hi', 'Hello-World', 'Earth'), ('Hello-World', 'Hi')]
tuple_new = [
    tuple([x.replace('-', ' ') for x in tup]) for tup in tuple_old
]
print(tuple_new)
```

FWIW, tuples are the things in parentheses. Lists are in square brackets. So you have a list of tuples, not a tuple of lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might help you to understand:

You cannot change a tuple or a string. you can only create a new one with different contents.

All the functions that "modify" a string are actually just creating a new string that has been modified from the original. Your original question that you referenced also slightly mis-understood one of the quirks of python where you can iterate over the characters in a string, but due to python not having a character datatype, they just end up as new strings. tldr; replacing "-" with " " looks just like this:

```
print("old-str".replace("-", " "))
```

This will generate a new string with all the dashes replaced.

Now you need to extend this to creating a new tuple of strings. You can create a new tuple with the built-in-function (which you had previously accidentally overwrote with a variable) `tuple` and passing in some sort of iterable. In this case I will use a generator expression (similar to [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but without the square brackets) to create this iterable:

```
tuple(entry.replace("-", " ") for entry in old_tup)
```

finally you can apply this to each tuple in your list either by creating a new list, or by over-writing the values in the existing list (example shows creating a new list with a list comprehension):

```
[tuple(entry.replace("-", " ") for entry in old_tup) for old_tup in worldstuff ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
worldstuff_new = [tuple(x.replace('-', ' ') for x in t) for t in worldstuff]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different way to do this you could use the map function like so.

```
tuples = [('Hi','Hello-World', 'Earth'), ('Hello-World', 'Hi'), ('Te-st', 'Te-st2')]

new_tuples = list(map(lambda tup: tuple(item.replace('-', ' ') for item in tup), tuples))
```

output:

```
[('Hi', 'Hello World', 'Earth'), ('Hello World', 'Hi'), ('Te st', 'Te st2')]
```